# How to create and call a function to mask credit card number

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *maskify(char *masked,const char *string);
main(void)
{
    char string;
    char display;
    char credit[9];
    printf("Enter credit card no: ");
    scanf("%s", &credit);
    display = maskify(credit,string);
    printf("Is credit card no: %s",display);
}
char *maskify(char *masked, const char *string)
{
    int n = strlen(strcpy(masked,string))- 4;
    if(n > 0)memset(masked ,'#' ,n);
    return masked;
}
```

pliz help in spotting the error

I was trying to achieve following output not for the test data but code is not working.
it bring a negative error.

```
sample_test("4556364607935616", "############5616");
    sample_test(     "64607935616",      "#######5616");

    sample_test(           "12345",            "#2345");
    sample_test(            "1234",             "1234");
    sample_test(             "123",              "123");
    sample_test(              "12",               "12");
    sample_test(               "1",                "1");
    sample_test(                "",                 "");

    sample_test(          "Skippy",           "##ippy");
    sample_test("Nananananananananananananananana Batman!", "####################################man!");
}
```

Comment: can you show a sample input and output?

Comment: `credit[9]` - 9 is too small if you want to handle longer strings like "4556364607935616".

Comment: What is `sample_test`?

Comment: What does your compiler think about this line? `maskify(credit,string);` You provide a single `char` where a `const char*` is expected. Similar for `printf(... %s",display);`. Don't ignore your compiler warnings. Read them, understand them and fix them. Do not try to run your program before you did that. If you did not get some messages, increase diagnostics level. For GCC or clang use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @Brian Noel, When `maskify(credit,string);` is called, what value do you think `stirng` has?